# Python: length of list odd or even

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of numbers which I want to calculate the total length, I need to find out if the total amount of numbers in the list is either 'odd' or 'even'. Moreover, hitherto, I can only seem to find **if the numbers in the list** are either odd or even.

Example of what I want to achieve: list = [4, 3, 8, 1] the answer would be an 'even' amount of numbers, as there are four numbers in the list.

```
numbers = [7, 2, 6, 5, 3, 1, 13, 8, 4, 9, 11]
for i in range (len(numbers)):
    length = 0
    if numbers[i] % 2 == 0:
        print("Even")
```

Comment: Why are you looping at all?  Just check whether `len(numbers)` is odd or not.

Comment: `if len(numbers) % 2 == 0: print('Even')`

Comment: Are you worried that the list holds other types than numbers?

Comment: You here are determining if the *elements* of the list are even or odd, not the length of the list.

Answer (score 5):

The comments are correct. Also, there's no need to use `numbers[i]` since lists are iterable.

```
if len(numbers) % 2 == 0:
   print ('Even')
else:
   print ('Odd')
```

Comment: You can also do `if len(numbers % 2): print('Odd') else: print('Even")` Or for a one-liner, `print(['Even','Odd'][len(numbers)%2])`.